# Handle keydown event perfectly with a canvas game

Tags: javascript, canvas, keydown

I'm actually doing a **snake game in JavaScript**, I found a **pretty nice tutorial** [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/think-like-a-programmer-how-to-build-snake-using-only-javascript-html-and-css-7b1479c3339e/).

After finishing it everything looks **good**, except **one thing.**

**When we keep one of the arrows pressed like the up arrow,** and then (while the up arrow key is pressed) **press the left or right key for exemple**, there is a huge chance that you **will have a delay** and your snake will only change his direction **after a little while.**

Here is the source code : https://codepen.io/Ziratsu/pen/LYYKOJP
(refresh to play again and don't forget to click on the document to be able to move your snake :)

I think the bug might comes from there :

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", changeDirection);

function changeDirection(event) {
      const LEFT_KEY = 37;
      const RIGHT_KEY = 39;
      const UP_KEY = 38;
      const DOWN_KEY = 40;
      /**
       * Prevent the snake from reversing
       */
      if (changingDirection) return;
      changingDirection = true;
      const keyPressed = event.keyCode;
      const goingUp = dy === -10;
      const goingDown = dy === 10;
      const goingRight = dx === 10;
      const goingLeft = dx === -10;
      if (keyPressed === LEFT_KEY && !goingRight) {
        dx = -10;
        dy = 0;
      }
      if (keyPressed === UP_KEY && !goingDown) {
        dx = 0;
        dy = -10;
      }
      if (keyPressed === RIGHT_KEY && !goingLeft) {
        dx = 10;
        dy = 0;
      }
      if (keyPressed === DOWN_KEY && !goingUp) {
        dx = 0;
        dy = 10;
      }
    }
```

This is actually where we **listen** for the **keydown** event and change direction if an **arrow key is pressed.**
There is a second place where the bug could comes in my opinion :

```
function main() {
      // If the game ended return early to stop game
      if (didGameEnd()) return;
      setTimeout(function onTick() {
        changingDirection = false;
        clearCanvas();
        drawFood();
        advanceSnake();
        drawSnake();
        // Call game again
        main();
      }, GAME_SPEED)
    }
```

This is the main function that we are **calling every 100MS,** maybe if we are pressing an arrow key for a little time the **code keep in mind the direction till the next 100MS are gone ?**

I also tried a lot of things, like using requestAnimationFrame to have a more smooth effect but without good results.

If someone has already worked with **keydown** or created some **browser** games, I would really appreciate a hand to remove that **delay**, that bug, for a better user **experience.**

Comment: Using `requestAnimationframe` is definitely the correct approach. But by using it there will be quite a bit of other refactoring you will need to do. Try this pen, the controls should feel much better (but stuff like eating will be broken): https://codepen.io/invalidusername/pen/rNNEpwB

 I'll help you refactor it if you want

Comment: Hey Brett thank's a lot, this is way more smooth !
Can you explain me a little what have you done ?
Why the parts of the snake are on each other and why the snake can't eat the apple now :) ?.

Comment: Sure, I think let's move this to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/203161/59055630?tab=general

Comment: Sorry wrong link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203161/59055630